# Writing an SQL Query to solve an SQL Puzzle

Tags: sql

I need a bit of help/direction as to how to write an SQL query using the following information:

[image]

The Question is:

> The manager would like to see all uf the cars currently in
>   the showroom and their price, in the following form: [Make] [Model] –
>   £[Price] e.g. “VW GOLF - 3000”. Write a SQL query to satisfy this
>   request.

__

I've broken it down into how I think it needs to work-

- First it needs to look at the CarID's in the showroom table and match them with ID in the car table
- Then it needs to display the model of the car from the Car table

  2,5,8 = fiesta, golf and 307
- Once the Name has been found, it checks the ParentCarID to see what the make is

  ford, VW and peugeot

The make and model are then displayed alongside the price making the result of the query:

```
CarID  Model    Make     Price

2      Fiesta   Ford     4000
5      Golf     VW       3000
8      307      Peugeot  5000
```

_

After watching and reading a lot about various queries I think that I need to use a relational query or a query with a join, i'd appreciate any help a lot :)

Comment: Did you try writing a join query and see for yourself if it works?

Comment: yeah, it just displayed a list of all the cars rather than just the ones that where in the showroom table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the make and model by joining the table onto itself via the parentID:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
    JOIN tableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.parentID
```

Then you just need to join the prices from the showroom table:

```
SELECT Model.ID, Make.Name, Model.Name, S.Price FROM car Make
    JOIN car Model ON Make.id = Model.parentCarID
    JOIN showroom S ON Model.ID = S.CarID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.MakeCode,
        a.ModelCode,
        b.Price
FROM    CarTable a
        INNER JOIN ShowRoom
            ON a.ID = b.CarID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: thanks for the comment JW, I tried this after watching this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJv6ZQlK_ek&list=UUbi5G5PjWBaQUFy7XU_O7yw&index=34 but it still shows the results of all cars  rather than just the ones in the showroom, 2,5 and 8

Comment: are you using `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

i hope this query will work has you expected.

select c.Makecode, c.madelcode,s.price from car c, showroom s where c.id=s.carid